# Is there a way to use multiple values search in datatables jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Is it possible to search multiple values in one column and at the same time I'm using server-side

if it's in the normal datatable without using any serverside this is working good.

```
table.columns(136).search("01|03",true,false).draw();
```

But when I change my datatables setup to server-side.
This one will stop working.

```
table.columns(136).search("01|03",true,false).draw();
```

Comment: If you're using server side data, then you need to write the search algorithm yourself. As such, you need to handle the splitting of the values by the pipe character (`|`) in your PHP (I assume from the tags) and then search for those values individually. Therefore, this is a PHP issue, not a Datatables/JS one.

Comment: Thank you  Rory McCrossan for your reply. Do I need to create a filter in PHP or custom query?